# How to configure maven-bundle-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, osgi, apache-felix

I am trying to convert and Eclipse plugin project to use Maven.  My existing project has the following MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Message Level Security Plugin
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.mls;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: MLS
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: com.ghc.ghTester.expressions
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,
 lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar,
 .
Require-Bundle: org.bouncycastle.crypto;bundle-version="1.46.0",
 javax.xml;bundle-version="1.3.4",
 org.apache.wss4j;bundle-version="1.5.11",
 org.apache.xml.security;bundle-version="1.4.3002",
 org.apache.commons.lang;bundle-version="2.6.0"
```

But I'm having a huge amount of difficulty figuring out how to configure the `maven-bundle-plugin` to generate my OSGI bundle properly:

I've tried:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
                <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.groupId}.${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                <Bundle-Name>${pom.name}</Bundle-Name>
                <Bundle-Version>${pom.version}</Bundle-Version>
                <Bundle-ClassPath>{maven-dependencies},.</Bundle-ClassPath>
                <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|provided</Embed-Dependency>
                <Import-Package>com.ghc.ghTester.expressions</Import-Package>
            </instructions>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

But how do I generate the "Require-Bundle" entry to use the maven dependencies I've listed as "provided"?

Ex:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Do I have to declare my dependency differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explictly add your `Require-Bundle` in the pom :

```
<Require-Bundle>org.bouncycastle.crypto;bundle-version="1.46.0", ...</Require-Bundle>
```

However, `Require-Bundle` is a bad (old?) practice. bndtools, behind the `maven-bundle-plugin` can generate for you the right `Import-Package`. You shouldn't use the `Require-Bundle` header anymore.

Moreover :

1. 1.4.0 is a very old version (2008). Try to use the latest version, 3.0.1
2. Add an empty `<Export-Package/>` tag : by default, this plugin export all packages but `*.internal.*` `*.impl.*`. If your package doesn't use this convention, you risk to export internal classes of your bundle.

Comment: Version was a bad cut & paste.  Should have been 3.0.0.

Comment: Basic question, but should my plugin.xml be in the src/main/resources folder?

Comment: I'm having trouble with the version numbers that the plugin is adding to the Import-Package line.  is there anyway to remove the versioning in the Import-Package?

Comment: I've create a separate question on SO for this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36188935/827480

Comment: Files in `src/main/resources` will be placed in the root of the jar. I don't know however where the plugin.xml should be located

Comment: plugin.xml should be in src/main/resources
@JérémieB even though <Require-Bundle> might be bad/old practice it is sometimes needed to get the proper packages.